# CAML "NOT IN" query

Tags: sharepoint, caml

Is there a way to do something like "NOT IN" behavior in SharePoint 2010? I can easily implement IN behavior like that:

```
<Where>
   <In>
      <FieldRef Name="ID"/>
      <Values>
         <Value Type="Counter">1</Value>
         <Value Type="Counter">2</Value>
         <Value Type="Counter">3</Value>
         <Value Type="Counter">4</Value>
         <Value Type="Counter">5</Value>
      </Values>
   </In>
</Where>
```

But is there a way to select all the values that DOES NOT IN Values enumeration?

Here is the USE CASE: I have a Lookup field with AllowMultipleValues = true, and I need to get all items from LookupList, which are not included into Lookup field

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Starting from SharePoint 2010, there's the `NotIncludes` element that might work for you. From MSDN:

> If the specified field is a Lookup field that allows multiple values, specifies that the Value element is excluded from the list item for the field that is specified by the FieldRef element.

Template:

```
<NotIncludes>
    <FieldRef Name="Field_Name" />
    <Value Type="Field_Type" />
    <XML />
</NotIncludes>
```

- [**More reading: NotIncludes Element**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff630174%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

To get the opposite behavior of 'In', you have to make a nested 'Neq' query. 'NotIncludes' could be substituted for or combined with 'Neq' if you are dealing with a Lookup Field with **multiple values**.

```
<Query>
    <Where>
        <And>
            <And>
                <Neq>
                    <FieldRef Name="ID" /><Value Type="Counter">5</Value>
                </Neq>
                <Neq>
                    <FieldRef Name="ID" /><Value Type="Counter">13</Value>
                </Neq>
            </And>
            <And>
                <NotIncludes>
                    <FieldRef Name="children" /><Value Type="Lookup">20</Value>
                </NotIncludes>
                <NotIncludes>
                    <FieldRef Name="children" /><Value Type="Lookup">32</Value>
                </NotIncludes>
            </And>
        </And>
    </Where>
</Query>
```

If you want more variables then more nesting needs to be done. Have fun.

Answer (score 0):

I think the Not equal option would be the best way to build this CAML query

Maybe this (didn't test this, so bear with me)

```
<Query>
   <Where>
     <And>
       <Neq>
          <FieldRef Name="ID" /><Value Type="Counter">1</Value>
       </Neq>
       <Neq>
          <FieldRef Name="ID" /><Value Type="Counter">2</Value>
       </Neq>
       <Neq>
          <FieldRef Name="ID" /><Value Type="Counter">3</Value>
       </Neq>
     </And>
   </Where>
</Query>
```

You should have a look at the available Comparison Operators

- Contains
- BeginsWith
- Eq, Equal
- Neq, Not equal
- Gt, Greater than
- Lt, Less than
- Geq, Greater than or equal to
- Leq, Less than or equal to
- DateRangesOverlap, Compare dates in recurring event with specified
  value
- IsNotNull
- IsNull

Comment: I don't think that CAML is valid as is - you can't have more than 2 children under AND IIRC.

Comment: Alright, I'll perform some tests and come back with the result when done!

Comment: Thank you all for the answer, but in case of using <And> operators query becomes a little ugly when the count of possible variants more than 10 (for ex.), by the way, I've solved this problem using <And> logic for now, but I think that it would be great if it will be possible to implement <NotIn> logic somehow...

Answer (score 0):

The closest I've come is to use `<NotIncludes></NotIncludes>`, but for some reason is does not work the same way as `<In></In>`. In `<In>` I can use `<Values>`. With `<NotIncludes>` it looks like you can only specify one value. The rest will have to be `<Or>`ed in, similar to `<Neq>`.